# Proof that a certain number is eigenvalue without performing diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have the following square matrix of order 3:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &  3 &  3\\ 
-3 & -5 & -3 \\ 
3 & 3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

How can I prove that $\lambda=-2$ is eigenvalue without having to calculate the characteristic polynomial and diagonalization?

I know the definition of  eigenvalue and I know how to diagonalize. But, I wouldn't know how to do that.

Comment: If you expect 2 to be an eignevalue, then your best bet imo is to compute $A-2I$ and try to spot a vector in the null space. Are you sure you mean $\lambda=2$ and not $\lambda=-2$?

Comment: If I calculate $A-2I$, what should I get and why?

Comment: 2 is an eigenvalue (by definition) iff there is a vector $v$ such that $Av=2v$. This is the same as saying $(A-2I)v = 0$, or $v$ is in the null space of $A-2I$. It is often easier to spot null vectors than eigenvectors in general.

Comment: NB: Comments above, and several answers (including the accepted one), are all for the question before @Carlos edited it to change $\lambda = -2$ into $\lambda = 2$, which is why some of them may look strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a really goofy answer: observe that 
$$
(A - I) (A + 2I) = 0
$$
hence the minimal polynomial of $A$ must be $$
m(x) = (x-1)(x+2),
$$
so that $-2$ must be an eigenvalue. (The question, as written, is wrong, and $+2$ is *not* an eigenvalue at all).

This meets the letter of the question without really teaching much, alas. How could one possibly guess that this product was going to be zero? Well, you could look at $I, A,$ and $A^2$, \begin{align}
I &= \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}\\
A &= \pmatrix{1 & 3 & 3 \\ -3 & -5 & -3 \\ 3 & 3 & 1}\\ 
A^2 &= \pmatrix{1 & -3 & -3 \\ 3 & 7 & 3 \\ -3 & -3 & 1}
\end{align}
and notice, from the regularity of the entries, that $A^2 + A - 2I$ is the zero matrix, and this factors as $(A-I)(A+2I)$. But why would you even think that the minimal polynomial was quadratic rather than linear? Well, $A + 2I$ is so 'repetitive' that you might guess, as I did, that it had only rank $1$ rather than rank $2$.

In other words, if this is obvious to you, it's easy. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a mistake as pointed out by John: it must be $\;\lambda =-2\;$ , **not** $\;\lambda=2\;$

Just check that $\;A+2I\;$ is singular, since that'd mean that there exists a vector $\;v\neq0\;$ s.t. $\;(A+2I)v=0\iff Av+2v=0\implies Av=-2v\;$. In our case we get at once:

$$A+2I=\begin{pmatrix}3 &  3 &  3\\ 
-3 & -3 & -3 \\ 
3 & 3 & 3\end{pmatrix}\implies \det (A+2I)=0\\$$

Comment: There's a small problem here: $-16 \cdot 8 = -128$, and not $-144$. That's because the correct eigenvalue is $\lambda = -2$ rather than $\lambda = +2$. I suspect the person posing the problem perhaps made the same computational error as @DonAntonio. (I'm also delighted to actually be able to correct a glitch in an answer from you, from whose answers I've learned so much!)

Comment: @JohnHughes I could have sworn that was a $\;-18\;$ ....Thanks, great catch. I shall edit and add that.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, 2 is an eigenvalue iff there exists **v** such that A**v**=2**v**. If you have such a **v**, you can prove that 2 is an eigenvalue simply by calculating A**v**. If you don't know such a **v**, then you'll have to calculate one, such as by taking the equation (A-2I)**v**=0 and solving for **v**.

Comment: "...iff exists $\;v\neq0\;$ ..."

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. $2$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$. Rather, $-2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

It is obvious that
$$
A+2I= \pmatrix{3&3&3\\ -3&-3&-3\\ 3&3&3}
$$
is singular. Since $\operatorname{tr}(A)=-3$ is odd, $A$ has an eigenvalue other than $-2$. As $A+2I$ has rank one, only one eigenvalue of $A$ can differ from $-2$, i.e. $-2$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity two. It follows that the other eigenvalue of $A$ is $\operatorname{tr}(A)-2(-2)=1$. Indeed,
$$
A-I = \pmatrix{0&3&3\\ -3&-6&-3\\ 3&3&0}
$$
is singular because its column sums are zero.